# Count Values in Column A when Column B is empty and vice versa

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count rows in a two-column range where at least one of the columns has a value. If both columns have values in the same row, I only want to count that row once.

It doesn't matter which column is counted when both have values, as long as that row is not counted twice.

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| Red |  |
| Blue |  |
|  | Fruit |
| Yellow | Banana |

The answer I'm looking for in this example is 4.

I'm using Google Sheets.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=rows(filter(A2:B, not(isblank(A2:A) * isblank(B2:B))))`

Comment: It worked! Can you explain how this formula works please?

Comment: See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra).